# How to increase the size of a Button in SwiftUI? (Multiplatform project)

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to increase the size oaf a Button in SwiftUI, Xcode 12.5 in a Multiplatform project:

```
Button("Click me") {
            // Perform action here
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

After checking the [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button) I found that I can style the button but I can not figure out how to make the click box larger. So that the entire yellow frame receives the click action not just the label.

Edit:

The The tap area problem is explained well here: https://alejandromp.com/blog/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/

[image: tap problem]

But the solution there to change add an element to the button and change the size of that does only work in an iOS project. In a Multiplatform project the frame of the button has the wrong size:

[image]

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
           Text("Click me")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
        })
```

Comment: use scale effect, but I am still not clear with what exactly you need.

Comment: I want the button lager. It is frustrating how hard this is in the current version. As all the examples from older versions do not work. scale effect does create a different issue. I will add it to the question. I also found an answer that works in the current version.

Comment: Maybe `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` - it gets rid of all default styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

**For iOS**

[image]

```
 Button(action: {
                //add actions at here
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Name")
                }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                
            }
```

**For macOS** (macOS version works well for iOS version too)

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
         
            
            Button(action: {
                //add actions at here
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Button Name")
                }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                
            }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? The padding is wrong with this solution as with most of the others. It will result in the the second image I have posted.

Comment: @kiatra ,  tested in iOS there was no problem. Was that you trying to achieve that in macOS?

Comment: @Seugjun , I have tested in in a multi-platform project. You are correct that it does work in an iOS platform project.

Comment: @kiatra hi I updated my answer to include macOS too, Could you check it again?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution where adding contentShape seems to do the trick:

```
Button(action: doSomething) {
        Text("Click me")
           .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
           .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

The button cannot recognize the modifiers on that place. The solution would be:

```
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Click me")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        })
```

Comment: This solution only works on iOS. I have edited the question to add that I made a multiplatform project.